# How do open source developers make money?

Tags: open-source

There are so many open source utilities that we all use like maven, subversion, etc. and all these open source platforms. How do these developers make money?

Comment: More of a question for Programmers StackExchange. Edit: In fact, it's already a duplicate: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/100685/making-money-with-open-source-as-a-developer

Comment: Many of them have day jobs.  A few probably work for companies that support their FOSS work.  A few might monetize their FOSS work by charging for support.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question. My bad.

Comment: There are many ways... donations, offering support... I did not make a response since i consider my answear too vague. I would like to view a detailled list of most common and effective ways to make money...

Comment: Many options, charge for support, dual license, donations, charge for the development of plugins...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I can think of four ways:

1) The open source project is a side project and have a job as their source of income

2) They have a corporate sponsor that pays the devs a salary

3) They develop their OSS project and then sell services based on that project (ie, I give away MySQL for free, and do consulting installing and maintaining MySQL for companies

4) They develop a base version of the OSS project, and then develop and sell commercial add-ons for it

Comment: I would like to add this line too. " They become famous and after that they can introduce many paid products and services "